# value head is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am executing twitter sample code, while i am getting error for value head is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row, can someone please explain little bit more on this error.

```
val tweets = sc.textFile(tweetInput)
    println("------------Sample JSON Tweets-------")
    for (tweet <- tweets.take(5)) {
      println(gson.toJson(jsonParser.parse(tweet)))
    }

    val tweetTable = sqlContext.jsonFile(tweetInput).cache()
    tweetTable.registerTempTable("tweetTable")

    println("------Tweet table Schema---")
    tweetTable.printSchema()

    println("----Sample Tweet Text-----")
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT text FROM tweetTable LIMIT 10").collect().foreach(println)

    println("------Sample Lang, Name, text---")
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT user.lang, user.name, text FROM tweetTable LIMIT 1000").collect().foreach(println)

    println("------Total count by languages Lang, count(*)---")
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT user.lang, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM tweetTable GROUP BY user.lang ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 25").collect.foreach(println)

    println("--- Training the model and persist it")
    val texts = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text from tweetTable").map(_.head.toString)
    // Cache the vectors RDD since it will be used for all the KMeans iterations.
    val vectors = texts.map(Utils.featurize).cache()
```

Comment: i am getting error in this line  val texts = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text from tweetTable").map(_.head.toString)

Comment: What's the scheme of tweetTable ? Does it have "head" column?

Comment: i am working on the below class, i am converting json tweets into table format and this json doesn't have head column.
 https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/twitter_classifier/scala/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitter_classifier/ExamineAndTrain.scala

Comment: @MuralikrishnaKonduru I think this code is wrong, check out the newest version if this file: https://github.com/databricks/reference-apps/blob/master/twitter_classifier/scala/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitterClassifier/ExamineAndTrain.scala

Comment: Thanks for referring me for correct source, i will try with this source code, Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the sql method returns a DataSet of `Row`s. Therefore the _ represents a `Row` and `Row` doesn't have a `head` method (which explains the error message).

To access items in a Row you can do one of the following:

```
// get the first element in the Row
val texts = sqlContext.sql("...").map(_.get(0))

// get the first element as an Int
val texts = sqlContext.sql("...").map(_.getInt(0))
```

See here for more info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html